# I am using iText to extract text from pdf file, I could able to see the text, however it losing structure of the page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, text-extraction

I am using iText to extract text from the pdf file, I could able to see all text value, but the structure is broken. Could you help me how to extract the text exactly like the pdf file. I've tried some online tool, it does the extraction correctly, what library they are using.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

if (File.Exists(ofd.FileName))
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ofd.FileName);

    for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
        //ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

        currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
        text.Append(currentText);
    }
    pdfReader.Close();
}
rtxtboxInvoice.Text = text.ToString();
```

Comment: Please share your pdf file, and explain what you mean by _structure of the page_. What do you expect and what is the actual result?

Comment: You have `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` in comments. Does it also not return the desired result?

Comment: For example, the text should be on one line, but when I do the extraction the text output is broken in 2 lines. SimpleTextExtractStrategy doesn't help. The expected output should be the same as the pdf file.

Comment: *"For example, the text should be on one line, but when I do the extraction the text output is broken in 2 lines."* - this often is a sign that the text in the pdf is *not* exactly on one horizontal line. The displacement might be small, even too small to notice for a casual viewer, but it's there.

Comment: This could be the reason, however when I use those pdf files with conversion tool on internet, it shows correctly.